# UWP app hang in the string FileIO.WriteBytesAsync

Tags: uwp, io

I use Win10 and code:

```
CacheFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.CreateFolderAsync(CACHEFOLDER, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
StorageFile _file = await CacheFolder.CreateFileAsync(key, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(_file, data);
```

file creates and byte[] saved there but exactly on the last string app hang. What maybe a reason? Where to dig? What is interesting, it happens not every run but very often.

Comment: Are you calling the code in an await-async manner? If you don’t call that way, compiler will give a warning, if you choose to ignore the warning you may encounter this problem.

Comment: yes, I wrap it in public static async Task<bool> SaveImage(string key, byte[] data)

Comment: And how do you call this method? Ensure the await-async is present all the calling chain.

Comment: I think to call this method I do not need await, because it has already in await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync.. Is it wrong?

Comment: I have do idea where to dig. The app hang and what is going on there? File is not locked and picture is there.

Comment: No, you are wrong. You also need to add await when calling SaveImage, and the caller’s caller...until you reach the top, for example, a button’s Click event handler: private async void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)

Comment: compiler tels that I have to use await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(_file, data); But any way. I think its minor problem because in debug mode I can not jump over this place. It does not metter how long do I wait. Any other idea?

Comment: sometimes app hang in the string StorageFile _file = await CacheFolder.CreateFileAsync(key, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting); What I am doing wrong?

Comment: the dir where I am wring is empty. No lock or not enought space problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrap this method in

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
...
}
```

It works.